# Quarto cross reference with stargazer

Tags: r, r-markdown, report, stargazer, quarto

I have a regression output which I use stargazer to report it in HTML format:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
#| label: tbl-reg-cox
#| tbl-cap: "Cox-estimations of first permit event"
#| output: asis

stargazer::stargazer(
    cox1,
    title="Cox regression",
    type="html",
    apply.coef = exp,
    df = FALSE
)

```
````

I want to reference it in Quarto markdown (.qmd) file, but when I am rendering it, Quarto Preview warns:

```
WARNING: Unable to resolve crossref @tbl-reg-cox
```

and the link appears as:

> Table ?@tbl-reg-cox

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? or are there any alternative to cross reference a code chunk?

thank you!

Comment: Do you need to use `stargazer`? You are doing it correctly, so if you choose another package to produce such tables, e.g. [gtsummary](https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary) it works better.

Comment: The problem with `stargazer` is that it generates some info about the package version and author at first and then outputs the table and since table is not the immediate output of the code cell, the cross-referencing is not working, which you can verify easily by running the document for `native` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using stargazer, use huxtable. Huxtable support all features that stargazer provides as well as several models including cox proportional hazard.

```
huxtable::huxreg(
    cox1,
    title="Cox regression",
    tidy_args = list(exponentiate = TRUE)
)
```